# How can I redirect visitors from my old Blogger site to my new one?

Tags: blogger

I want to know how to automatically redirect visitors from posts on my old Blogger site to the same posts on myt new site.

Old blog: `http://freeebooktips.blogspot.com`

New blog: `http://free-ebook-tips.blogspot.com/`

Comment: Question URL redirect might be asked on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

Go to your code and search for `<b:include data="blog" name="all-head-content"/>` or after the `head` tag paste the following line below it.

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://www.yournewdomain.com' />
```

change *[www.yournewdomain.com](http://www.yournewdomain.com)* with your domain. [more info about redirection here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161112104058/http://www.bloggertipsseotricks.com/2015/06/add-custom-redirect-post-url.html)